# How to group by milliseconds?

Tags: postgresql

```
select 
floor(extract( epoch from recieved ) - extract( epoch from created )) as n,
count(*)
from table 
group by n
```

now it is grouped by exact milliseconds but I want it to be grouped in time intervals 100 milliseconds. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Normalise each value to the interval it is in, then group by that

Comment: Easiest way to do that: divide by 100.